# ros-by-example vol2. roslaunch in CH4 xacro error

Tags: roslaunch, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*ros-by-example vol2.*

*CH4 CREATING A URDF MODEL FOR YOUR ROBOT*

**The command line is shown below:**

```
$ roslaunch rbx2_description box_robot_base_only.launch
```

**The error message is shown below:**

```
 root@ShawnVM:~/catkin_ws/src/rbx2/rbx2_dynamixels# roslaunch rbx2_description box_robot_base_only.launch 
... logging to /root/.ros/log/0d82b658-a196-11e6-9533-000c290a3fdb/roslaunch-ShawnVM-48840.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid <arg> tag: xacro
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks. 

Arg xml is <arg default="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find rbx2_description)/urdf/box_robot/box_robot_base_only.xacro'" name="urdf_file"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247136/ros-by-example-vol2.-roslaunch-in-ch4-xacro-error/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have solved this problem.

The problem was caused by **NOT doing roscd pkg-name before roslaunch** .
Thus, file cannot be loaded correctly.

Another solution is using absolute path.

Reference to :http://answers.ros.org/question/141466/error-in-building-a-visual-robot-model-with-urdf-from-scratch/

---

Originally posted by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) with karma: 339 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0